# Gensim.Similarity Add document or Live training

Tags: python, nlp, similarity, gensim

A little background about this project. I have copies with an identifier and the text, e.g. `{name: "sports-football", text: "Content related to football sports"}`.

I need to find the right match for the given text input within this corpus.
However, I was able to achieve somewhat using Gensim. Similarity with LDA and LSI Model.

How to update the `Genism.Similarity` Index with new a document. The idea here is to keep training the model at live stage.

Here is the step I followed.

QueryText = "Guardiola moved Lionel Messi to the No 9 role so that he didn't have to come deep and I think Aguero drops back into deeper positions too often."

Note: some codes are just layman

The index is created using

```
`similarities.Similarity(indexpath, model,topics)`
```

1. Create A dictionary

   `dictionary = Dictionary(QueryText )`
2. Create a corpus

   `corpus = Corpus(QueryText, dictionary)`
3. Create an LDA Model

   `LDAModel =  ldaModel(corpus,dictionary)`

Update existing dictionary, model, and index

Update existing dictionary

```
existing_dictionary.add_document(dictionary)
```

Update existing LDA Model

```
existing_lda_model.update(corpus)
```

Update existing Similarity index

```
existing_index.add_dcoument(LDAModel[corpus])
```

Other than below warning update seems to be worked.

```
gensim\models\ldamodel.py:535: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp2 perwordbound, np.exp2(-perwordbound), len(chunk), corpus_words
```

Let's run the similarity for the query text

```
vec_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(QueryText) 
vec_model = existing_lda_model[vec_bow] 
sims = existing_index[vec_model]
```

However, it failed with below error.

```
Similarity index with 723 documents in 1 shards (stored under \Files\models\lda_model)
Similarity index with 725 documents in 0 shards (stored under \Files\models\lda_model)
\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ldamodel.py:535: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp2
  perwordbound, np.exp2(-perwordbound), len(chunk), corpus_words
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-8fe711724367> in <module>()
     45 trigram = Trigram.apply_trigram_model(queryText, bigram, trigram)
     46 vec_bow = dictionry.doc2bow(trigram)
---> 47 vec_model =  lda_model[vec_bow]
     48 print(vec_model)
     49 

~\Anaconda3\envs\lf\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ldamodel.py in __getitem__(self, bow, eps)
   1103             `(topic_id, topic_probability)` 2-tuples.
   1104         """
-> 1105         return self.get_document_topics(bow, eps, self.minimum_phi_value, self.per_word_topics)
   1106 
   1107     def save(self, fname, ignore=('state', 'dispatcher'), separately=None, *args, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\envs\lf\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ldamodel.py in get_document_topics(self, bow, minimum_probability, minimum_phi_value, per_word_topics)
    944             return self._apply(corpus, **kwargs)
    945 
--> 946         gamma, phis = self.inference([bow], collect_sstats=per_word_topics)
    947         topic_dist = gamma[0] / sum(gamma[0])  # normalize distribution
    948 

~\Anaconda3\envs\lf\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ldamodel.py in inference(self, chunk, collect_sstats)
    442             Elogthetad = Elogtheta[d, :]
    443             expElogthetad = expElogtheta[d, :]
--> 444             expElogbetad = self.expElogbeta[:, ids]
    445 
    446             # The optimal phi_{dwk} is proportional to expElogthetad_k * expElogbetad_w.

IndexError: index 718 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 713
```

I really appreciate, helping me with this.
Looking forward to awesome replies.

Answer (score 1):

The later error (`AssertionError: mismatch between supplied and computed number of non-zeros` in the sparse matrix) most likely comes from the issue suggested by the warning - `perwordbound` overflows and the matrix calculated using its *undefined* value fails the update.

I suggest updating the model with larger batches (not a single query). There may be a disproportionate number of words, count of words in the model that you are trying to update with a relatively small number of words. For floats this may cause [subtle errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Again, please try updating the model with batches of size proportionate to the model source data (e.g. 1/10th, 1/20th of its size).

---

Revision, based on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/zYmQGxADztU):

> **Melissa Roemmele** wrote:
>
> FYI, I also got this error when I tried to create an LSI index for a
>   corpus on a bag-of-words corpus without first transforming it into
>   tf-idf. I could build the LSI model on the bag-of-words but building
>   the index for it gave me the error.

You may want to try tf-idf first before passing the `QueryText` to the model.

Comment: I defiantly try that. However, it won't solve my problem. What I need is keep training the model as when we required. What steps i need to follow then?.

Comment: Here is a git hub repo if someone wants to take a look. https://github.com/nithinshiriya/NLPLive

Comment: Have you applied tf-idf as the cited reply suggests?

Comment: This problem is not solved yet. I have gone through gensim issues on github but no luck found.